# Chrome extension: Cookies and Webview mutual exclusivity workaround?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

[Question edited]:

The chrome manifest for 'webview' and 'cookies' seem to be mutually exclusive. Is there a way to get them to work with each other such that we can open a mobile website (such as hotmail) on a desktop in a app/ext popup with the login already stored as a cookie? (That is if the user is already logged in, I don't want them to have to relog in, however using `partition="persist:somePartition"` works so far to require the user to only login once per browser per device).

Permission errors from manifest:

```
//manifest.json
{
...
"permission":["cookies","webview","https://*live.com/*"],
..
}

//webview //error:only allowed for packaged apps (not extensions). This is an extension.
//cookies //error:only allowed for {extensions/legacy packaged apps} (not packaged apps). This is a packaged app.
```

I'm aware that there is a way for two apps to communicate with each other, however I'm hoping for a simpler work-around.

Comment: are you writting an app or an extension?

Comment: docs already tell you cant have both

Comment: That's already known. Thanks anyway, if you have an answer feel free to post it.